# How can I remote control an SVN client from a different box

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, vpn, rdp

We have recently changed our development infrastructure and where we previously had a single dev server with developer machines connecting directly to the repo on dev, we now have multiple dev servers that connect to the repo on our CIS.

Original setup:

Developer Machine (SVN Client) -> Dev Server [Repo]

New setup

Developer Machine (Mapped Dev folder) -> Dev Server n (SVN Client) -> CIS [Repo]

The problem we have created is that the only way to commit or update the working copy which is stored on one of the dev servers is via RDP.  This works but is a little bit cumbersome.

Some local devs run tortoise fine on their dev boxes over the mapped drive but they are sat on the local network, however I am a remote dev and connect via VPN so this kind of operation is not even an option.

Does anyone know of an SVN remote?  Has anyone else dealt with this kind of indirect working copy access?

Comment: This can't work. Devs need to run the svn client on their machine. This is a recipe for near-complete non-productivity.

Comment: @bmargulies Yes it is currently a significant barrier, especially for remote devs.

Comment: The obvious approach is to run the Subversion client on each local developer box and contact the repository though HTTP or SSH. Is there a management ban on this solution?

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario Not for any reason beyond that is how it used to be done I am sure it can be negotiated.  I think our issue here is the introduction of the intermediate dev servers which are proving to be quite a barrier. One of the big issues with using the VPN client locally is the time it takes to scan the files on the mapped drive. A local copy sync'd with the mapped drive would solve this performance issue though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention how you are accessing the repository, I'm guessing "directly connecting" means *file:* scheme.

Personally, I'd install [Subversion Edge](http://www.open.collab.net/go/csvne2_r2a/) on your CIS repository server, configure it to point to your existing repositories, then [relocate](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-relocate.html) your developer working copies to the http(s) scheme supported by Subversion Edge.

This will make (AD) domain authentication (via LDAP) and encryption (HTTPS) relatively simple to implement should you wish to expose your repository externally, i.e. outside of your internal network.

We just went through this process for our company (30+ svn users) and it was a pleasant experience.

Comment: Hi Si.  Many thanks.  Yes that seems like the solution.  We can then SVN directly to CIS and let Subversion Edge sync the repositories.